# What's the successor of mrunit?

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, mapreduce, mrunit

Today I found out that the ASF retired mrunit (see https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/the_apache_news_round_up85 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3733 and the [homepage itself](http://mrunit.apache.org/)). Other than "inactivity" there was no reason given, so I guess there has to be an alternative?

What's supposed to be used instead of mrunit to unit test mapreduce jobs in the future?

Comment: Did you manage to find anything ?

Comment: No. It seems we're supposed to clone the project and maintain it ourself.

Comment: Found something that can be useful, check answer post

Comment: @SaifAsif: ok, but where is this "answer post"?

Comment: Undeleted it, you can check it now.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the reason for this retirement is the realization that Mockito already can handle what you need to unit test your mapper/reducers. All you need is to mock your Context, Counter and HBase KeyValue and you can then pass in a row (in the form of the Result object) to a mapper and check if the key/value emitted is correct.

FYI - I actually got my MR unit tests working perfectly using this approach without any assistance from MRUnit and PowerMock.

Comment: This would be a better answer if there was actually some example code associated with it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I left the company since I wrote this. Yeah, I should have given sample code. It was fairly tricky to setup if you are a newbie to mockito unit testing in java...

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a successor, but I tried and tested a work-around with a bit of research. It is actually based on the [Minicluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html) module of hadoop.

To find out how to use it, details can be found [in this link here](http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/hadoop-testing-with-minicluster/). And a github demo project  [exists here](https://github.com/bobfreitas/minicluster-mr2).

Comment: One upvote for the research. Indeed we're already using `MiniDFSCluster` in one instance and surely could use it more. But it's not the answer I'm looking for, because the MiniCluster is more of a functional level test. We also want to cover the unit level aspect (so basically just the map/reduce methods)

Comment: @DavidOngaro Correct, I am also thinking to expand using MiniDFSCluster and include some unit testing in it as well.

Comment: detail link expired