# How to unit test Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop2

How to unit test Hadoop Mapper and Reducer logic in 2016? Yes, I've heard about about mrunit, but Apache retired it 2 years ago. So, how do you unit test mapreduce nowadays?

I use Hadoop 2.7.3 version.

Comment: refer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288176/whats-the-successor-of-mrunit